# arbitrary utf8 characters in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdf, unicode

I'm generating a pdf with xelatex that could contain arbitrary utf8 printable characters.  Assuming I don't greatly care what font ends up being used for any particular character, how do I get most/all of the characters to be properly output?  Is there a font that will support all unicode printable characters?  If not, what are the pluses and minuses of various fonts?  Are there characters other than `{}_#%&$` that need to be escaped or otherwise specially treated?

Comment: All Unicode? I don't know any such font.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font lists the main "large" fonts eg gnu unifont covers the BMP, but that still leaves the math alphabets which are in plane 1

Comment: BMP only would be a good start.  I see https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2014/12/10/xelatex-unicode-font-fallback-unsupported-characters/ which (assuming it works) could be applied per other script

Comment: The question title was edited to ask for a specific font.  While I mention fonts in the body, that isn't the question; the question is how to handle arbitrary utf8 characters

Comment: For CJKV ideographs, you have [Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/), which covers all CJKV ideographs in the Unicode 10.0 standard, including the *entire* Supplementary Ideographic Plane (SIP, there are 60,317 in total). It does not, however, cover the 5 newly added ideographs in BMP in Unicode 11.0. BTW, Hanazono is not particularly well-designed as its purpose is to merely cover all Unicode ideographs. I don’t see a purpose of a pan-Unicode font. You could also try the Google Noto font families.

Comment: There are 87,887 Unified Ideographs in Unicode 11.0, and CJK Ext. G is proposed to the [Tertiary Ideographic Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/tip/) (Yes, a brand new plane!). No single `.ttf` or `.otf` file is capable of covering all CJK ideographs as the maximum number of glyphs allowed is 65,535 per file.